# Plotting ordinal data with a marker in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data for which I have experimental and simulated values, the data isn't really continuous without introducing a new definition (which I don't want to do) so I wish to display it ordinally in a scatter type plot with two markers for each set and then label each set on the X-axis.

Basically I can't figure out how to do this with matplotlib (I'd prefer to use it for consistency with how I've presented other data).

An example of the data is presented below:

**1cm square:** `0.501, 0.505`

**1cm circle:** `0.450, 0.448`

**1cm X 2cm rect:** `0.665, 0.641`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but it sounds like you're wanting something along these lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Using this layout to make the grouping clear
data = [('apples', [0.1, 0.25]),
        ('oranges', [0.6, 0.35]),
        ('pears', [0.1, 0.18]),
        ('bananas', [0.7, 0.98]),
        ('peaches', [0.6, 0.48])]

# Reorganize our data a bit
names = [item[0] for item in data]
predicted = [item[1][0] for item in data]
observed = [item[1][1] for item in data]

# It might make more sense to use a bar chart in this case.
# You could also use `ax.scatter` to plot the data instead of `ax.plot`
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(predicted, color='lightblue', marker='o', linestyle='none',
        markersize=12, label='Predicted')
ax.plot(observed, color='red', marker='s', linestyle='none',
        markersize=12, label='Observed')

ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set(xticks=range(len(names)), xticklabels=names, ylabel='Meaningless')
ax.legend(loc='best', numpoints=1)
ax.grid(axis='x')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The key part is setting the xticks and xticklabels to correspond to your data "groups".  You could plot the data in a few other ways (e.g. bar plots, etc), but using the xticks/labels will be the same in each case.

Comment: excellent y axis